# Declare time in milliseconds in a readable way (clean code)

Tags: java, android

I'd like to declare a constant like:

```
private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_REQUESTS = 12*HOURS;
```

instead of

```
private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_REQUESTS = 43200000;
```

Is there some existing class I could use for the HOURS value? or should I declare it in my project something like:

```
public static final long SECONDS=1000;
public static final long MINUTES=60*SECONDS;
public static final long HOURS=60*MINUTES;
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try **TimeUnit from java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit**. It best serves your purpose

TimeUnit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: +1 I would use the Javadoc from Java 6 for Android, or Java 7 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a basic formatting issue. If you want to express your time in hours then the simplest way is to write it out in your expression the long way, and replace the variable "hours" with an integer literal representing how many hours you want to wait.

```
private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_REQUESTS = (1000 * 60 * 60) * hours //replace hours with what you want the value to be
```

I hope I understood what you were trying to do well.

Comment: Thanks, thats the method I was using till now, but asked because if you want to declare 7 days (1000*60*60*24*7) is slower to understand than 7*Time.Days